# How to create read-only pendrive (no availability of coping, deleting or overwriting)

Tags: usb, file-system, file-access

I want to create pendrive or external HDD, that is read only.
To be precise - I want to be open to read files on it (documents or video files), but to prevent files from being copied off disk.
As I know BitLocker gives possibility to block files totally, or give full access after entering a password.
Is there something that gives more levels of data access?

Comment: You want to be able to access the file, run that file in the computer's memory, open it into a program ... but disable the writing of what's already in memory to file? I don't think that will work... the control is not on the USB but on the computer... It also sounds like the goal of a DRM. Note that DRM attempts have failed spectacularly over the years (someone with physical access always finds a way).

Comment: There are lots of ways to disable deleting or modifying files on a storage medium (pendrive), but your question body isn't about that.

Comment: Example: I have pendrive with PDF. I want it to be able to open it from pendrive and read, but i dont want that someone could copy it on its PC.

Comment: Right - I explained why that can't work

Comment: You would need a specialised PDF reader that blocked the saving of the file. And that's not making the pendrive read-only. That's file protection that have nothing to do with the pendrive. And is a type of DRM, which is difficult to do well.

Comment: You can maybe use `diskpart` to set `attributes volume set readonly` but I think it's easy to remove as well with `attributes volume clear readonly`. Alternatively, and I wouldn't recommend relying on it for critical or forensic purposes. An alternative to perhaps achieve the same result you want, is by blocking the 'write to removable storage'-function on the machine, rather than on the drive itself. See: https://github.com/digitalsleuth/Registry-Write-Block. Readonly means copy is of course possible too. At best you can make it harder to write (changes) to the drive.

Comment: I found software, that gives what i need.
https://www.kakasoft.com/

Comment: Right, that's DRM software. And you have to run that software to read the files. As I explained. That's not about protecting the USB.